# Laravel BelongsToMany Pivot Table : How to fetch selected columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Want to get selected columns, when querying through pivot table. Following is my scenario.
I have 3 tables,

- coupons
- coupon_cities
- cities

relationship details are as following.

```
class Coupon extends Eloquent {

    public function cities(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('City', 'coupon_cities', 'coupon_id', 'city_id');
    }
}
```

When I query

```
Coupon::with('cities')
```

it returns array of all columns of city table for each entry of coupon row

Answer (score 0):

The only way is this:

```
$coupon = Coupon->first();
$coupon->cities()->get([your columns here]);
```

Normally you'd do it like below:

```
Coupon::with(['cities' => function ($q)
{
  $q->select('column', 'column2' ...);
}
```

**However it won't work for `belongsToMany` relation** -> https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4440

Comment: yes, that last line, that I was about to say. I've applier this eager loading, but it was not working. In short, it's not possible. Right?

Comment: Unfortunately that's correct. Why do you need that anyway?

Comment: perhaps you'll laugh. It shows me timestamps as well, so I want to avoid it. Larvel does `city.*`, which I want to avoid

Comment: Exactly, you can't avoid that `table,*` in this case. Anyway, if you're outputting it just like that, consider using transformers.

Comment: Hey dude! transformers? New to me. Please share me a link, I'll go through. Thanks

Comment: Check these out: https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Transformers http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/